# How can I make all the points on a dense plot visible in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using this basic code to display a plot using matplotlib. The lists for the x and y axis are large.

```py
plt.plot(r,trajectory,"k.")
plt.title("Bifurcation diagram")
plt.xlabel("R")
plt.ylabel("Xn")
plt.show()
```

How can I format my plot better to view all the details?

With the above configuration what I see is

[image: Initial]

But what I want to get to is something that looks like this with each point visible (atleast high enough resolution to zoom in)

[image: final]

Update:
I found that tuning the available parameters iteratively can yield good results. Used a combination of the answers below to understand parameters and arrive at this configuration.

```py
f = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4),dpi=300)
plt.plot(r, trajectory, "k,", markersize=0.01, mew=0)
f.savefig("bifurcation_diag.png")
plt.title("Bifurcation diagram")
plt.xlabel("R")
plt.ylabel("Xn")
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma as marker, not a dot. The [comma marker](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/markers_api.html) is just one pixel, while the dot is one "point". Set `mew=0` to avoid that an outline is drawn, as the outline would be much larger than a pixel. You can also add `alpha=0.2` (or similar) to have semi-transparent pixels.

This is how it could look like with:

```py
plt.plot(r, trajectory, 'b,', markersize=.1, mew=0, alpha=0.2)
```

[image: example plot]

PS: The full code to reproduce the plot:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def logistic_map(x0, r, num_iter):
    x = np.zeros(num_iter)
    xi = x0
    for i in range(num_iter):
        xi = r * xi * (1 - xi)
        x[i] = xi
    return x

def bifurcations(x0, r_min, r_max, r_steps, num_iter, iter_to_skip):
    r_values = np.linspace(r_min, r_max, r_steps)
    bifurcations = [logistic_map(x0, r, num_iter)[iter_to_skip:] for r in r_values]
    plt.plot(r_values, bifurcations, "b,", markersize=.1, mew=0, alpha=0.2)
    plt.show()

bifurcations(0.1, 2.4, 4, 500, 1000, 5)
```

Setting `alpha=0.1` and `bifurcations(0.1, 2.4, 4, 2000, 2000, 500)`:

[image: more detailed plot]

Comment: Thanks for including a snippet. However, I'm not able to reproduce these results when I use ```plt.plot(r,trajectory,"b,", ms=.1, mew=0, alpha=0.2)```. This is the [result](https://imgur.com/a/bee6B7R). Since comma is at the level of pixels, is it possible I am missing something in terms of plot size/dpi? (I have not modified either of this in my code)

Comment: Try to use a larger alpha (or leaving it out). I probably used more iterations than you, so getting a darker plot when more pixels are aggregated.

Comment: I used the same number of iterations (n & k). But I used rsteps=0.01. rsteps should be increments of r right? Is that a typo (rsteps=500) in your function call?

Comment: No typo. When using `np.linspace(...., ...., rsteps)`, `rsteps` is the number of steps (e.g. `500`). If you'd use `np.arange(...., ...., rstep)`, `rstep` is the size of the step. A stepsize of `0.01` would be `160` steps.

Comment: Thanks! I took the approach of incrementing rmin by rstep value each time instead of dividing (rmax-rmin)/rsteps. Your previous inference now adds up since your step increment is 0.0032. This output is good but a configuration that would allow zooming in to the plot get a fine grain view of the points would be extremely helpful (to notice fractals and other features). I wonder if matplotlib is the right package to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **smaller marker size**. The problem is that there are so many data points that they are overlapping resulting in a dark image.

I explain this below using an example dataset. The left figure shows default marker size and the right figure shows the same data with a smaller marker size using argument `ms=1`. You can choose `ms=2`, `ms=3` etc. as per your need.

```
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

# Default marker size
ax1.plot(np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000), np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000), 'k.')

# Smaller marker size `ms=1`
ax2.plot(np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000), np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000), 'k.', ms=1)
```

[image]

Comment: you can also set the default marker size for your code using `import matplotlib as mpl` and then `mpl.rcParams['lines.markersize'] = 1`

Comment: Thanks! I used ```plt.plot(r,trajectory,"k.", ms=1)``` and reached a better [version](https://imgur.com/a/IA18maZ). Is there something I might be missing? Your plot with higher number of points looks much more fine grained compared to mine.

Comment: I experimented with lower marker sizes (eg. ms=0.1) but don't notice the plot getting better. Image [here](https://imgur.com/a/ksTCmMf)

Comment: @rs747 : Can you try adding `, mew=None` too?

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/MY8gUE8) is what I got with ```plt.plot(r,trajectory,"k.", ms=1, mew=None)```
I definitely have an issue with the number of pixels in the plot as I can barely zoom into it. The specific study that I'm using this for involves "fractals" basically self-similar patterns when you zoom in. It would be extremely helpful if I could get a high-res image with maximum points visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can obtain this result by setting the transparency of the plot. Try this:

```
#just add alpha to your plt.plot() method
plt.plot(r,trajectory,"k.", alpha=0.2)
```

Comment: This did not seem to make a difference. Image [here](https://imgur.com/a/tz9f41B). My intention is to have a fine grain view of the large number of points.

Comment: Try smaller values though... try `alpha=0.005`

Comment: With smaller values of alpha the points seem to fade away as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/eRm6hQj). Not quite the intended effect

Comment: I think all it needs is some parameter tuning. I believe a suitable number for `alpha` will lead to a much better graph